# Finding out who owns a Google Analytics UA code

Tags: google-analytics

An old client got in touch asking about GA access, but is isn't something we have and the company we believe has it isn't claiming ownership either.

Is there a way to contact Google to ask who the owner of a particular UA is? Or anyway to do it without Google?

I should mention, we don't want ownership, we just want to track down who has it and point the client in the right direction.

Comment: If you have ftp access to the site you could claim ownership.

Comment: also if you only want to see who is the owner, this service might help (not 100% reliable of course) http://www.spyonweb.com/

Comment: Thanks @milo5b but we don't want ownership, we just want to be able to pass on who does to the client. Also I presume claiming ownership would be like setting up a new GA account so historical stuff would get lost. Finally, we don't have FTP access.

Comment: Thanks again for the spyonweb.com suggestion, that is what we used to ascertain who we think is looking after it, but as I say they are saying they don't - we really need a canonical answer from somewhere official.

Answer (score 11):

It's not a direct answer, but one way you might find out what *other* sites are on the same Analytics account is to use a reverse lookup. Assuming multiples (since this seems like a client situation, that could give you a hint who the owner is or at least a few other leads for people to contact and work your way back.

Comment: Seems to be broken now.

Answer (score 4):

I have had to do this many times when taking over SEO services for clients.

Send an email to adwords-support@google.com, or have the person that wants access send the email. Explain the situation and tell them you need access to the GA account. You will get an email back that looks like this:

[image]

As long as you have FTP access it isn't a problem. Happens pretty quick in my experience.

Comment: seemed like a great answer but email is no longer being monitored

Comment: Emails have to be sent through https://support.google.com/analytics/ now, with the "Contact us" button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the information from Google.   They state their policy about identifying the owner of a Google Analytics id [here](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/4QHNkwiIu_M/wbA5CD57O3cJ):

*AnalyticsPro.Aruna said:*

> Unfortunately, due to account security issues, we're unable to disclose or add logins to Google Analytics accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Try www.domainmetrics.de to find out to whom a certain analytics-id belongs 
(no knowledge of the german language neccessary).

Comment: Hi Frank, you don't need to sign your posts since they're already signed with your user card in the bottom right. Your personal information and website, should you choose to share them, can & should go in your personal profile.

Comment: domain no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

Try emailing Google, look for the help/support section in Google Analytics. Another way would be having the client claim it and then it will show all the owners when your client logs in.